# Export Public Key parameters from Crypto++ ELGamalKeys

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I am using CryptoPP and trying to export the steps of each encryption/decryption so I can learn how ElGamal works.

I have been trying to learn ElGamal encryption by way of this site:

https://cryptographyacademy.com/elgamal/

I am able to find the SubgroupOrder, SubgroupGenerator, and Modulus of an ElGamalKeys::PublicKey, but I am unable to find the 3rd parameter of the PublicKey which is computed using Alice's private exponent. According to the site:

```
 Next Alice chooses the secret key sk=a between 1 and p−1 and computes A=g^a mod p

Alice then publish the public key pk=(p,g,A).
```

How do I access the A parameter from the PublicKey explicitly?

Comment: A is part of the public key, you don't have to "find" it.

Comment: I know it is part of the ElGamalKeys::PublicKey instantiated object. I want to extract it's Integer value from that object. I updated my question to be more explicit.

Comment: I believe I have found it. In ElGamalKeys::PublicKey there is a parameter called "PublicElement" that corresponds to the A value I was seeking.